# 羨ましく思える　か　羨ましいと思える　か

Tags: translation, meaning

１.羨まし**く**思える　と　羨まし**いと**思える　は　何が違いますか？

そして

１．羨ましいと**思う**　と　羨ましいと**思える**　は　何の違いがありますか？

説明が難しい場合例文をください、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 羨ましく思える　と　羨ましいと思える　は　何が違いますか？

I think they are almost the same.

> 羨ましいと思う　と　羨ましいと思える　は　何の違いがありますか？

The former usually takes a person as a subject, whereas the latter usually describes an inanimate object (either as a predicate or as a relative clause). You can compare them with similar English pairs such as "to envy" and "enviable", "to regret" and "regrettable".

- 私は彼の家のことを羨ましいと思った。
- 彼の家は羨ましいと思える家だった。